# Bedeutung von "hinter sich wissen"

Tags: phrase, meaning-in-context

Aus [der Süddeutschen Zeitung](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/politik/bundestagsdebatte-zur-sterbehilfe-sterben-ist-das-letzte-1.2215657):

> Derzeit zweifelt nur die Grüne Künast am Sinn eines Verbotsgesetzes. Sie will Sterbehilfevereine zulassen und ihnen Auflagen zur Qualitätskontrolle machen. Ein Verbot würde das Tabu nur vergrößern, würde Menschen in Not die Chance eines ergebnisoffenen Gesprächs nehmen, schrieb sie im *Tagesspiegel*. **Die Bevölkerung, die sich in Umfragen immer wieder mehrheitlich für Sterbehilfe ausspricht, weiß sie hinter sich.** Auch im Parlament sind viele Abgeordnete unentschlossen. Die Debatte ist erst am Anfang.

Was bedeutet "weiß sie hinter sich" hier? Heißt es, dass sie gut weiß, wer die Leute sind, die immer wieder Sterbehilfe unterstützen? Ich habe mir die Bedeutungen von [hinter sich](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/hinter) mit mehreren Verben angeschaut, aber diesen Satz verstehe ich noch nicht.

Comment: Der Titel ist unglücklich gewählt, denn "etwas hinter sich wissen" heißt "know that it's past". "Jemanden hinter sich wissen" however is "knowing that someone supports your claim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Das Wort *„wissen“* kann verschiedene Bedeutungen haben. Meistens entspricht die Bedeutung sicherlich dem ersten Eintrag im [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wissen): *„durch eigene Erfahrung oder Mitteilung von außen Kenntnis von etwas/jemandem haben, sodass zuverlässige Aussagen gemacht werden können.“*

In diesem Zusammenhang bedeutet *„wissen“* jedoch *„davon Kenntnis haben, sicher sein, dass sich jemand/etwas in einem bestimmten Zustand, an einem bestimmten Ort o. Ä. befindet, sich etwas in bestimmter Weise verhält.“* Dabei handelt es sich um eine gehobene Ausdrucksweise.

> jemanden zu Hause wissen
>   sich in Sicherheit wissen
>   sich geborgen wissen
>   seine Kinder bei jemandem in guten Händen wissen
>   er wollte diese Äußerung ganz anders verstanden wissen

Um den Text in der Frage zu verstehen, muss man außerdem wissen, dass der Ausdruck *„hinter jemandem stehen“* im übertragenen Sinne auch *„jemanden unterstützen“* bedeuten kann:

> „Sie wird von der Bevölkerung unterstützt.“
>   → „Die Bevölkerung steht hinter ihr.“

Mithilfe beider Ausdrücke zusammen könnte man also wie folgt umformulieren:

> „Sie ist sicher, dass sie von der Bevölkerung unterstützt wird.“
>   → „Sie ist sicher, dass die Bevölkerung hinter ihr steht.“
>   → „Sie weiß die Bevölkerung hinter sich.“

Answer (score 1):

Nein, es heißt nicht, dass sie die Leute kennt. Es bedeutet, dass Frau Künast die Bevölkerung hinter sich weiß, weil die Bevölkerung in Umfragen immer wieder mehrheitlich der gleichen Meinung wie sie in Bezug auf Sterbehilfe ist. "Hinter sich wissen" bedeutet bildlich ausgedrückt, zu wissen, dass die Bevölkerung (in Bezug auf die Meinung zu diesem Thema) hinter ihr steht, so dass man sich stärker fühlt, als wenn man alleine wäre.

Comment: Du solltest einen Unterschied zwischen "jemanden hinter sich wissen" und "etwas hinter sich wissen" machen